# Favicons not showing in Safari 5.1.1 on OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, safari

Since upgrading to Safari 5.1.1 none of the websites I am visiting is displaying Favicons. I had a look in `~/Library/Safari/Icons` to try and reset these but noticed that the file/folder doesn't exist, so the problem is not related to the caching.

This was working fine in a clean install of Lion before upgrading to 10.7.2. Even installing Glims and setting the icons to display in the tab headers did not fix the problem.

Is anyone aware of a fix for this, or whether this is a known bug?

Comment: I'm running Safari 5.1.1 on Lion (10.7.2) and see the favicons.

Comment: And, to be sure, I did a Safari -> Reset Safari, and removed Website icons, then refreshed the page. I see the favicon again.

Comment: And that directory doesn't exist for me either, but I still see the icons.

Comment: @Alex WIll give it a try now, I think I may need to do a repair permissions again :( I seem to have to do that often lately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research it turns out I am not the only one with this problem, and Safari has changed the location for it's favicon database.

From [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3372748?start=0&tstart=0) Apple Forum discussion:

> - Quit Safari.
> - Go to ~/Library/Safari. 
>     Move the WebpageIcons.db file from the Safari folder to the Trash.
> - Relaunch Safari.

Comment: The key here is the Relauch, just emptying cache and refreshing does nothing.

Comment: Followed directions above--problem is that when I relaunched Safari the Webpagelcons.db file was recreated and the favicons still don't appear!
LG

Comment: Forgot to mention that I upgraded to OS10 10.7.4 (using Safari 6.0)--could this explain the missing favicon problem??

Comment: just tried this, Safari 6.0, OS 10.7.4. The site I'm checking is using a PNG for its favicon, but other sites using .ico files work ok. Haven't tested more than a couple yet, but worth considering